# How to change CSS-Style with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a small script for Greasemonkey, but it does not work, because I have little experience.

It is necessary to replace all properties CSS with a value (background: #fff;) on (background: #e8e8e8;).

Comment: To change CSS you use Stylish instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Background color change
// @namespace   https://website here
// @description Changes the background color
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

document.body.style.background = "white";
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add,

```
GM_addStyle("body { background-color: #fff !
    important; }");
```

*Important may not be needed.*

Comment: "As of Greasemonkey 4.0, this method has been removed." (https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle)